# My Leetcode solution works in "Run Code Result" box, but not in the "Submissions box"

Tags: python

I just completed problem #174 - Dungeon Game https://leetcode.com/problems/dungeon-game/

My code runs perfectly and is correct when testing it in Leetcode's own "Run Code Result" box with the EXACT same testing parameters, but it fails in the submissions box. Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    min_hp = 0

    def calculateMinimumHP(self, dungeon, pos_x = 0, pos_y = 0, init_hp = 1, damage = 0) -> int:
        damage += dungeon[pos_y][pos_x]
        
        if init_hp + damage <= 0:
            init_hp += 1
            return Solution.calculateMinimumHP(self, dungeon, pos_x, pos_y, init_hp, damage - dungeon[pos_y][pos_x])
        elif init_hp > Solution.min_hp and Solution.min_hp != 0:
            return
        elif pos_x + 1 == len(dungeon) and pos_y + 1 == len(dungeon[0]):
            Solution.min_hp = init_hp
            return Solution.min_hp
    
        if pos_x + 1 < len(dungeon):
            Solution.calculateMinimumHP(self, dungeon, pos_x+1, pos_y, init_hp, damage)
        if pos_y + 1 < len(dungeon[0]):
            Solution.calculateMinimumHP(self, dungeon, pos_x, pos_y+1, init_hp, damage)
    
        return Solution.min_hp
```

Any ideas would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "submit", LeetCode tests your solution with multiple test cases. It *does* create a new `Solution` instance for each test case, but that's all the "freshness" you get. So your problem is that your `Solution.min_hp` doesn't get reset to zero between test cases.

A quick fix would be to reset it yourself when a new instance is created:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        Solution.min_hp = 0

    def calculateMinimumHP(self, dungeon, pos_x = 0, pos_y = 0, init_hp = 1, damage = 0) -> int:
        ....
```

It then fails on a later test case, as you appear to have another bug.

Comment: Thank you! I'll fix the bug on my own, but this was driving my crazy.